# How to manually overrule flex property for specified element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `section` in my page which has a `h1` and 3 `div`. I set the `display` property of the `section` to `flex`; and so the `h1` as well as the `div` aligned themselves one after the other.

I want the `h1` to be in the top center ignoring the `display` property and then the 3 `div` to be right below it. Something like this-

[image]

Also, please tell me of a more efficient or conventional way to do so.

Here's my HTML and CSS code:

```css
/* Why choose Section */

#Why_choose{
  height: 800px;
  background: #12121;
  display: flex
}

#Why_choose h1{
  color: white;
}

#Why_choose h2{
  color: #e50914;
}

#Why_choose p{
  color: white;
}

#Why_choose img{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="Why_choose">
    <h1>Why choose Snap Smile Veneers</h1>
    <div class="invisible">
      <img src="images/random_img.jpg">
      <h2>we invisible</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
         elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
         dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>
    <div class="comfortable">
      <img src="images/random_img.jpg">
      <h2>we comfortable</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
         elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
         dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>
    <div class="workHome">
      <img src="images/random_img.jpg">
      <h2>we work from home</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
         elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
         dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: min-width: 100% on the h1

Comment: Is not working, it's just pushing the divs next to it, so now i get a horizontal scroll

Comment: @SahilSingh can you provide small image explaining what do you need?

Comment: Oops, flex-wrap: wrap on #Why_choose

Comment: @Simp4Code still not working, now the h1 and divs are stacked one on top of the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `flex-wrap: wrap` in oder to make the rest of the items begin in a new line like that:

```css
#my-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#bottom-flex-items {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section id="my-flex">
  <h1>Top center h1 Title</h1>
  <div id="bottom-flex-items">
    <div>
      <h2>First One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Second One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Third One</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: doesn't work, the h1 and divs are stacking one on top of the other. I've added an image of how I want them to display

Comment: Have you tried it like in the example? Using another flex `div` that wraps your three divs that contain the `img`, `h2` and `p`

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks for helping me out. I created another container div and kept all the initial divs in it, removed the display flex property from the section and applied it only to the container div.

Answer (score 1):

in here one approach is that,you can wrap comfortable,workHome and invisible section with new div.in here I wrapped with section two div.give Why_choose section display flex and flex direction cloumn.giv section two to display flex.in order to center the text inside #Why_choose h1 give css propetry text-align:center to it.working code is below,

```
 <section id="Why_choose">
      <h1>Why choose Snap Smile Veneers</h1>
      <div class="section-two">
        <div class="invisible">
          <img src="images/random_img.jpg" />
          <h2>we invisible</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="comfortable">
          <img src="images/random_img.jpg" />
          <h2>we comfortable</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="workHome">
          <img src="images/random_img.jpg" />
          <h2>we work from home</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section> 




#Why_choose {
  height: 800px;
  background: #12121;
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
}
.section-two {
  display: flex;
}
#Why_choose h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#Why_choose h2 {
  color: #e50914;
}

#Why_choose p {
  color: white;
}

#Why_choose img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: grid`

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 } h1 { margin: 0 }

/* Why choose Section */

#Why_choose {
  background-color: #121212;
  color: white;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#Why_choose h1 { grid-column: 1 / -1 }
#Why_choose h2 { color: #e50914 }
#Why_choose img{ width: 50% }
```

```html
<section id="Why_choose">
  <h1>Why choose Snap Smile Veneers</h1>
  <div class="invisible">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300">
    <h2>we invisible</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comfortable">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300">
    <h2>we comfortable</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  </div>
  <div class="workHome">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300">
    <h2>we work from home</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
  </div>
</section>
```